# Higher order derivative From $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

If function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,\;(x,y) \mapsto (x^2+y,y^2+x)$
Then What about continuity and Derivative at $(0,0)$?
And how to find $Df(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Looks like homework...

Answer (score 1):

You can just compute the partial derivatives and apply theorems known to you ;-) ... or you can have fun and apply directly the definition:

Given $x \in \mathbb R^2$, in order to find $Df(x)$ we have to find a linear $A\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that
\[
  f(x+h) = f(x) + Ah + o(h), \quad h \to 0 
\]
Now, 
\begin{align*}
  f(x+h) 
  &= \bigl((x_1 + h_1)^2 + x_2 + h_2, (x_2 + h_2)^2 + x_1 + h_1\bigr)\\
  &= (x_1^2 + x_2, x_2^2 + x_1) + (2x_1h_1 + h_2, 2x_2h_2 + h_1) + (h_1^2, h_2^2)\\
  &=: f(x) + Ah + (h_1^2, h_2^2) 
\end{align*}
We have
\[
  \frac{\|(h_1^2, h_2^2)\|}{\|h\|} \le 2\frac{\|h\|^2}{\|h\|} \to 0, \quad h \to 0
\]
and therefore $(h_1^2, h_2^2) = o(h), h \to 0$. Hence $f$ is differentiable in $x$ with
\[
  f'(x)h = (2x_1h_1 + h_2, 2x_2 + h_1)
\]
As the title of your question asks for higher order derivatives, we will compute $f''(x)$. So let $h, k \in \mathbb R^2$, then
\begin{align*}
  f'(x+k)h &= \bigl(2(x_1 + k_1)h_1 + h_2, 2(x_2 + k_2)h_2 + h_2\bigr)\\
      &= f'(x)h + (2k_1h_1, 2k_2h_2)\\
      &=: f'(x)h + \bigl(f''(x)k\bigr)h 
\end{align*}
There is no nonlinear term, so $f$ is twice differentiable. As $f''\colon \mathbb R^2 \to L\bigl(\mathbb R^2, L(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^2)\bigr)$ is constant, $f$ is smooth with $f^{(n)} = 0$ for $n \ge 3$. So $f$ is also continuous.